# How do I code to determine range of movement of an individual from imported data

Tags: excel, import, angle

I recently started learning NetLogo and have some questions regarding programming problems.

So I realize that "rt", "lt" and "fd" allow you to set direction and distance you move.

However, if I were to have a list of angle and distance to move for an individual as an outside program (e.g. excel or csv file), and use them for the range,

So for example, I would have a list of angles (0, 0, 2, 3, 6, 10, 100, 20) that I obtain from laboratory experiment and would like to determine the angle of an individual by randomly choosing from that list.

How am I supposed to code it?

Comment: Dear Luke, your question lacks research effort. The community is here for helping with specific programming questions, not for doing your work. If you want to use NetLogo, then I suggest to google for "NetLogo tutorial" as a start.

Comment: Hello ffonz, I am very remorseful if I ever offended you with my question in anyway. Again, I am very new to this so I was trying to seek help in any sort of ways. I did read up the "NetLogo tutorial" that you suggested but maybe due to my lack of background in coding in general I might have missed what i needed. I actually tried to look for the function that I need online for about 2~3 weeks but I suppose the more you know the more you see eh? But anyways I realize I might have been too early to join this community so um good luck to you too.

Comment: No hard feelings, a lot of newbe's make this mistake. You didn't offend me with your question, I just wanted to explain how it works here. And my answer could have been a little more polite: "your question seems to lack..." When you know a little more about programming, we are glad to help you here. And read the FAQ about how to ask good questions.